# Get an unique list by objects id efficiently

Tags: typescript, time-complexity

I have an array of `projects`. Each `project` has an array of `employees`. Each employee has an unique identifier `id`. I would like to combine all `employees` from all the `projects` in an array, but remove duplicates.

I thought about creating a `Map<number, Employee>` first with the key being the employees id. That way i can check whether the map already has the employees `id` as a key and only add him to the map if it doesn´t:

```
this.projects.forEach(project => {
  project.employees.forEach(employee=> {
    if (!this.employeeIdToEmployeeMap.has(employee.id)) {
      this.employeeIdToEmployeeMap.set(employee.id, employee);
    }
  })
});
```

Afterwards im able to get the values of the map and transform them to an array:

```
this.employees = Array.from(this.employeeIdToEmployeeMap.values());
```

Now i have all `employees` from all the `projects` without any duplicates.

Is there a better way to do it? Can it be done in O(n)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce method to achieve that:

```
const projects: { employees: { id: any }[] }[] = [
    { employees: [{ id: 2 }, { id: 7 }] },
    { employees: [{ id: 5 }, { id: 7 }] }
];

const map = projects.reduce((employees, project) => ({
    ...employees,
    ...project.employees.reduce((emps, employee) => ({
        ...emps,
        ...(emps[employee.id] ? {} : { [employee.id]: employee })
    }), employees as any)
}), {} as any)

console.log(Object.values(map)); // Prints: [ {id: 2}, {id: 5}, {id: 7}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a trivial O(nlogn) solution:

1. put all the employees in a list
2. sort the list
3. add employees to a new list while skipping consecutive duplicates

What is the complexity of your solution? Well, converting the map to a list should be O(n) given any sort of reasonable implementation of the map. The outer loop body executes n times. So, the question is, what is the complexity implied by adding an element to a map? Worst-case time is clearly linear (assuming a list-based bucket and open hashing; could be log(n) if using a tree or something instead), best-case time is constant. Here, since our problem is fundamentally about putting n items into a map, we need to know the amortized complexity. Using a resizable backing store and multiplicative expansion when it detects it has run out of space, I'd expect it's feasible to get O(1) amortized complexity for the add operation. If that's how your map works, what you have is O(1) assuming a good hash function.